# How to validate oracle security token coming from external system

Tags: java, oracle, single-sign-on, oracle-access-manager

I'm trying to integrate my web app with an external system where the user will login in external system (which I do not have control of ) using Single Sign-On with **Oracle Access Manager 11g** then can access my web-app without the need to login again .. is it possible to **validate** the user token which comes from the **Oracle Access Manager**?

Answer (score 0):

Your application must "plug in" to OAM using an OAM WebGate so that OAM can validate the token. This is typically done through the web server.

See here for an example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/doc.1112/e49451/webgate_apache.htm#WGINS76147